# Is it possible to use regexp to find root of a tree in fully parentheses representation?

Tags: java, regex

I want to find root of a tree when it is represented in fully parentheses form like this:

```
(s (A (B b)(C c))(D (E e)))
```

I have tried this:

```
(\(\s*(\S+)\s+(\([.^\)]*\))*\))
```

but It doesn't match anything. I want to extract S and its leaves where in this example they are `(A (B b)(C c))` and `(D (E e))`.

I guess fully parentheses form is not a regexp. Am I right?

Comment: It is possible in some regex flavors. Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with regexp. I'm using java regexp to find that

Comment: In principle this cannot be done using regex, you need a context free grammar to parse this. Try a recursive strategy using depth-first (as long as it's a tree). You at least need a stack to count occurrences of `(` or `)`.

Comment: I thought when we have center embedding we need CFG. Anyway I can't Understand what's wrong with the regexp I've provided above....I'm really confused why it doesn't work

Comment: unfortunately java regex doesn't have the tools to do that *(Some other languages have a regex engine able to do that: Perl, PHP, R, .net)*, you need to write a parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue**

This issue cannot be solved using a regular expression because the set of strings you want to use it on do not form a regular language. This language is somewhat equivalent to the balanced parentheses language, which is a *context-free* language.

**Solutions**

One way to solve this is using context-free grammars but as this is not a standard Java feature (to the best of my knowledge), this strategy is not advised in your context.

A better way would be to use a stack (which gives power to context-free languages). The idea is simple:

```
parse the string from left to right
   create an empty stack
   if next char is '('
       throw it on the stack
   else if next char is ')'
       pop from stack
   if stack is empty
       current position is the root
       return substring from 0 to here as left leaves
       return substring from here to end as right leaves
```

This of course in pseudo code.